# Node.js TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url

Im trying to parse some urls using url module and http server.

Code bellow:

```
var http = require('http');
var URL = require('url');
var port = 8080;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var parsedURL = URL.parse(req.URL, true).pathname;
    switch(parsedURL) {
        case 'test/myurl':
            console.log('Valid URL.');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('404!')
    }
});

server.listen(port);
console.log('Service at port: ' + port);
```

gives following error:

```
TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
```

at this line:

```
var parsedURL = URL.parse(req.URL, true).pathname;
```

Anyone can help? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: try using `req.url`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url property name for an [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) object is:

```
req.url
```

not

```
req.URL
```

thus, `req.URL` is `undefined`.